# Alinhamento não funciona em uma div

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando alinhar uma div no centro, mas ela fica na esquerda. Já tentei usar `<div align="center">`, tentei usar `text-align` e `align-items` no css, mas nada funciona.

```css
#json {
      background-color:rgb(59, 54, 54);
      color:rgb(204, 198, 198);
      border-radius: 8px;
      width: 300px;
      align-items: center;
      text-align:center;
   }
```

```html
<div id="json"> Conteúdo aqui </div>
```

Comment: adiciona um `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: funcionou, obrigado!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Centralização horizontal
>
> Para centralizar algo horizontalmente em navegadores modernos, você pode utilizar display: flex; justify-content: center;
>
> Contudo, em navegadores antigos, como IE8-9 que não suporta layout flexbox, estes não estão disponíveis. Para centralizar um elemento dentro de seu pai, use margin: 0 auto;

[Fonte: Margin - developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/margin#notas)

```css
#json {
      background-color:rgb(59, 54, 54);
      color:rgb(204, 198, 198);
      border-radius: 8px;
      width: 300px;
      text-align:center;
      margin: 0 auto;
   }
```

```html
<div id="json"> Conteúdo aqui </div>
```